# pgpool-II connection pooling (only) but for long running transactions, can it even be done?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, postgr

I have a job queue management system where workers fetch a job from a queue and maintain that job record locked, they use save-points to make other database changes and, on error, roll back to that save-point still holding on to the locked job record. Then finally update the job result/status and commit.

Since I sometimes need hundreds of workers, I am running into the problem of PgSQL database connection limits (I have 100 configured right now, but that scratches the limits of memory, etc.) So I thought to use pgpool-II to have more connections.

Until I considered the fact that they all hold onto a locked record, or any transaction. And so the problem/question is, would pgpool-II even help here or would it not keep the connection locked while a transaction is running?

In that case I would have to change my logic, not to lock the job records but update them.

Right? Any other idea? Why does PgSQL require so much memory for each possible connection anyway, if my connections actually don't do very much most of the time?

Answer (score 0):

With a work queue I would usually "lock" a record in user space by updating a field to indicate that it has been locked and committing that update. That way other users can see that is locked, and by who, and maybe why and when.  The disadvantage is that they this type of "lock" won't be released automatically  if the connection rolls back or is lost, so you need some kind of monitor (either human or program) to declare when the locks have been abandoned and undo them.

But that doesn't necessarily solve your problem.  Presumably the connection is still doing something and that something could still block pooling from sharing the connection.  The problem is, you haven't told us much of anything about what that something is, so we don't know how you would work around it.

The mere existence of a connection uses some memory, but not very much.  Any plausibly-sized server could support many hundreds of bare connections. The memory problems would come from what those connections are doing, and again we don't know much about that.

Why do you need hundreds of workers at a time? I would generally work on making each one faster so you don't need hundreds at a time, rather than working to support hundreds at a time.  Maybe there is a good reason you need to have hundreds at a time, but without knowing what that reason is we can't really offer specific advice.